# Mysqli is causing login form not to work at all

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a little issue with my login form. I think the problem is mysqli code because when the code was old mysql code, the login worked correctly but since I changed it to mysqli, it has not quite worked properly.

What is suppose to happen is that the user will enter in their username and password in the login form, when the user clicks on the "Login" button, it will check in the database if the username and password is correct. If it is correct then navigate to the menu.php page else if login is incorrect, display a message stating log in is incorrect, try again.

Instead what the code below is doing is that when the user enters in their username and password and clicks on "Login" button, no matter if username and password is correct or not it just refreshes the from, it doesn't navigate to menu.php page or display a login incorrect message.

So my question is that why is this happening, why after logging in does it not navigate the user or display the incorrect login message?

CODE IS UPDATED TO SHOW CURRENT CODE:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // PHP code
    session_start(); 

    $username="xxx";
    $password="xxx";
    $database="mobile_app";

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database)or die( "Unable to select database");

    foreach (array('teacherusername','teacherpassword') as $varname) {
            $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
          }

    // move this outside the condiitonal
    $loged = false;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM Teacher t  
    WHERE 
    (t.TeacherUsername=?)
    AND
    (t.TeacherPassword=?)
    ");

   $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_param("s",$teacherusername);
   $stmt->bind_param("s",$teacherpassword);

   $stmt->execute(); 

   $stmt->bind_result($TeacherId,$TeacherForename,$TeacherSurname,$TeacherUsername,$TeacherPassword);

    while($row=$stmt->fetch())
      {

          if ($_POST['teacherusername'] == ($row['TeacherUsername']) && $_POST['teacherpassword'] == ($row['TeacherPassword']))
          {
              $loged = true;
          }

$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $row['TeacherForename'];
$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $row['TeacherSurname'];
$_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $row['TeacherUsername'];

      }

      if ($loged == true){
      header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;
    }
    }

     ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Teacher Login </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LoginStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php if ($loged == false && $_POST) {
  echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";
  }
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">        
    <p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
    <p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password--> 
    <p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

I have turned error reporting on and with the code above which I retrieved from one of the answers, it is giving me a warning and a fatal error which are below:

```
Warning: mysqli::prepare() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /web/stud/xxx/Mobile_app/teacherlogin.php on line 33

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /web/stud/xxx/Mobile_app/teacherlogin.php on line 34
```

What do these means and does anyone have any ideas how to fix them? I updated the code above to show current code.

Comment: Well firstly it appears you are trying to mix mysql and mysqli functions. With prepared statements you don't need to use the _real_escape_string but use ?'s as placeholders. For more info try: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php but as afuzzyllama said your main problem is not putting the redirect / session stuff above your html.

Comment: @SteveH I have updated code so it uses prepare statements and thus not mix up mysql and mysqli functions. It is still not working though

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: @user1421767 - Yes please see my updated answer to resolve your issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE / EDIT:

Following on from your comments, I took another look at your mysqli code and noticed a number of mistakes you made (multiple prepare and bind_result statements and a few other things). I have updated the below code which has made a few improvements / should resolve your issue. I wasn't too sure on your db schema, but it is always better to actually state the columns you want rather than using (*) as if you add another column in the future and don't update the code, it will break your mysqli statement as the bind_result won't match your query.

```
<?php
  // PHP code
  session_start(); 

  $username="xxx";
  $password="xxx";
  $database="mobile_app";

  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

  // required variables (make them explciit no need for foreach loop)
  $teacherusername = (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) ? $_POST['teacherusername'] : '';
  $teacherpassword = (isset($_POST['teacherpassword'])) ? $_POST['teacherpassword'] : '';
  $loggedIn = false;

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ? AND TeacherPassword = ? LIMIT 1";
    // prepare query
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$teacherusername,$teacherpassword);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(); 
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherId,$dbTeacherForename,$dbTeacherSurname,$dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
      if ($teacherusername == $dbTeacherUsername && $teacherpassword == $dbTeacherPassword) {
        $loggedIn = true;
      }
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();

    if ($loggedIn == true){
      // left your session code as is - but think wisely about using
      // the Username as a session variable (security risk)
      $_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $dbTeacherForename;
      $_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $dbTeacherSurname;
      $_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $dbTeacherUsername;
      header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;
      die();
    }
  }
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <?php if ($loggedIn == false && $_POST) {
    echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";
    }
  ?>
  <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">        
  <p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
  <p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password--> 
  <p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update / Edit:**
To Note I have changed this text because it didn't make sense now I have rewritten most of your code. If the above does not work (as in you still get a mysqli error) it means your Teacher table has more than 5 columns.

An important FYI would be the connection between the $mysqli->prepare and $stmt->bind_result statements, these need to match in terms of number of selected columns. You can name the variables in bind_result what ever you want, but the number of variables need to match the number of columns you selected in you SELECT statement, hence why explicitly naming you columns is always better than (*).

Comment: I have turned error reporting on and by using your code I am getting a warning and a fatal error. I have updated question to show current code (which is your code) and the two php errors I am getting

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay much attention to your mysqli code as I assumed it was correct. Basically your syntax for the mysqli is wrong, you are trying to pass in a prepare statement into another prepare statement. I will update the code in my answer to correct your query.

Comment: @user1421767 Please look at my updated code - should correct your issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your HTML. You have an IF for the input form after the html. Add the html to an else for that if like below:

```
session_start(); 

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="mobile_app";

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database)or die( "Unable to select database");

foreach (array('teacherusername','teacherpassword') as $varname) {
        $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
      }

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$query = $mysqli->prepare("
SELECT * FROM Teacher t  
WHERE 
(t.TeacherUsername=?)
AND
(t.TeacherPassword=?)
");

$loged = false;

$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$teacherusername);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$teacherpassword);

$stmt->execute(); 



$stmt->bind_result($TeacherId,$TeacherForename,
                    $TeacherSurname,$TeacherUsername,$TeacherPassword);

while($row=$stmt->fetch())
  {

      if ($_POST['teacherusername'] == ($row['TeacherUsername']) && $_POST['teacherpassword'] == ($row['TeacherPassword']))
      {
          $loged = true;
      }

   $_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $row['TeacherForename'];
   $_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $row['TeacherSurname'];
   $_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $row['TeacherUsername'];

  }

  if ($loged == true){
  header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;
}else{
  echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";
}


}else{
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">        
<p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
<p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password--> 
<p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p>
</form>
<?php
}
 ?>
```